# Remove MapFragment

Tags: android, mapfragment

I have a MapFragment and regular Fragments in my app. The problem is when I change between the fragments, the MapFragment is in the background. I have code to find if the MapFragment is there, but I need code to remove it.

Code:

```
FragmentMapView mapFragmentcheck = (FragmentMapView)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("map");
if (mapFragmentcheck != null) {
    Log.d("tag","max exists");
    if (mapFragmentcheck.isVisible()) {
        Log.d("tag","map is visble, remove it");    
         // Do remove here, but how?
    }
}
else {
    Log.d("tag","map does not exists");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```js
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
 super.onDestroyView();
 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity()
   .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_add_place);
 if (mapFragment != null)
  getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .remove(mapFragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't find this simple answer on many other high voted questions.

Answer (score 2):

The code would be:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragmentcheck).commit();
```

Make sure to read the documentation on [`FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) in order to understand more about how to change fragments.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW: You don't need to add [SOLVED] to your solved questions. Simply accept the answer, that helped the most. The site will take care of the rest. Also high acceptance quotes increase the probability of people answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

I was adding Google Map like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    Bundle bdl = getArguments();

    // setuping locatiomanager to perfrom location related operations
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Requesting locationmanager for location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);

    // To get map from MapFragment from layout
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    // To change the map type to Satellite
    // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    // To show our current location in the map with dot
    // googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // To listen action whenever we click on the map
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            /*
             * LatLng:Class will give us selected position lattigude and
             * longitude values
             */
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), latLng.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    changeMapMode(3);

    // googleMap.setSatellite(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    return v;
}
```

My map in xml looks like this

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="ScrewMaps" />
```

I am Detaching Fragments like this :-

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        android.app.Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (null != fragment) {
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                    .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Please Note that my MapView Fragment is  **android.app.Fragment** & I am using **getFragmentManager()** to add and remove MapViewFragment. If  you are mixing V4.Fragment operations with app.Fragment your app will crash badly